# Regex match only a base tag's href attribute?

Tags: html, regex

I've managed to match href values of any tag using this:

`(?<=href\=["'])(.*?)(?=["'])`

Given the following:

```
<base target="_blank" href="http://test.test">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
<a href="test">test link</a>
```

It will match the values of each attribute. But is it possible to only match the URL of the base tag?

(Note we can't look ahead from 'base href=' because the href might not be the first attribute, as in the example above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
/<base [^>]*href=\"(.*?)\"/
```

The general idea is that you just match an opening `<base` tag, then find the first quoted value that appears after an `href`, but before any `>` characters. This will break if any of the other attributes have a `>` in them, but that shouldn't be a practical concern, and if it is, you should use a real HTML parser to extract the attribute value.

Comment: Right, but I'm looking to match only what's contained as the value. This would totally work and I can dissect the string elsewhere, but if it's possible with a regex alone that would be ideal.

Comment: That regex uses a single capture group; the first capture group will contain just the URL. Does your regexp implementation not support capture groups?